# Create regular grid in QGIS from coordinates in excel file

Tags: qgis, excel, grids-graticules

I have received an excel file that contains data on grid cells of 500X500m. The geographical information looks like this: 13843145006371500. The first four digits is the code for the municipality and the others are the xy-coordinates for the south west corner of the grid cell. Can I use this information to create a grid in QGIS?

I use QGIS 2.10 on windows 10

Comment: The first step is to add a separator between the 3 data fields. If the fields are fixed width, i.e. the number of characters per field is fixed, you can use Notepad++ and its handy column editor mode to add a separator like a space or comma. Of course Notepad++ reads ASCII files so you'll have to convert your XLS file to CSV.

Comment: Is it a complete rectangular grid of NxM cells with values of some quantities defined in the cells? Because if it is, then its better represented as a raster image than a set of points. Turning that spreadsheet into a raster will need a bit of processing. Can you post a screenshot of the spreadsheet, or at least the first few lines and columns?

Comment: @Techie_Gus you can split the field in Excel with some substringy formula, create three new columns, save to CSV, read into QGIS but you get a point data set which might not be right if the data is more like a raster grid...

Comment: 13843145006371500 is 1384 for the muni code and then 3145006371500 for the x,y, but that's an odd number of digits. Where's the break between X and Y? Do you know the coordinate system being used here? (UTM maybe?)

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I need to have vector based cells so a raster grid or points are not an alternative. The coordinate system is epsg  3007 (sweref99 12 00). I'm also confused about the odd number of digits. There should be the same amount of digits in the x and the y coordinate, shouldn't it?

Comment: The number of digits should not necessarily be equal for X and Y. If you look at the CRS details in the link (http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/sweref99-12-00/) you can see that X starts with 5 digits then goes up to 6 but Y is always 7. The thing I see with your figure is that X seems to start with a 3 which makes it fall out of the projection bounds. Y is ok though. Just a note on the bounds, they are in the form LLX, LLY, URX, URY.

Comment: @Spacedman my comment was not meant as a complete solution but just one step in the right direction. I proposed Notepad++ for the simplicity of splitting data in columns by using column edit mode without requiring the use of string formulas in excel, something not everybody is familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS can load geographic data from a CSV file via Layer --> Add Delimited Text Layer. If you would like to load the grid data as polygon, you will have to format the data in the WKT format.

Your end result should be something like this

> wkt|mun_code|...
>
> POLYGON ((3145006 371500, 3145006 372000, 3145556 372000, 3145556
>   371500, 3145006 371500))|1384|...
>
> ...

Note that I am adding 500m to the X,Y coordinates to form a grid polygon in the WKT format. (Tip: Use | as the delimiter since WKT string contains commas)

The formatting can be done in Excel with formulas so you have a column with wkt geometry. Once you have the CSV file, it could be loaded in QGIS.